# How do I efficiently hold this table containing many bit fields in memory, using a structure?

Tags: vb.net, data-structures

In VB.Net, what would be the proper way to hold in memory a structure consisting of bit fields not nicely aligning up at whole bytes, and being interpretable in at least 2 ways, depending on a specific bit. Do I just define constants and extract the fields with their help, or do I build a structure?

The input into the table is actually just 32 bytes from a bit stream. Its content does not change once in the structure.

Access should be by field name, so I assume some kind of structure would be the way to go, including bit manipulation on the fly? Time-efficiency is all what counts.

This is the table in question (if interested, it's an MP3 frame's side information):[image]

Positions and lengths are in bits, not bytes.

Comment: You could define a structure that contained a single data object, like a `BitArray` or a `Byte` array or whatever is most convenient, then simply add properties that use bit masks to access the specific bits required for the corresponding field.

Comment: If memory isn't an issue, and speed is your only concern, and it's read-only and will be read many times once in memory, then it may make sense to interpret the raw data and store it in a more easily accessible structure using normally typed properties rather than storing it as the raw data and reinterpreting it every time.  The footprint in memory will be larger, but it may be worth if to not have to reinterpret the data every time a property is read.  It all depends on how big it is and how often it's read.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Of this structure (if any) just one record is held in any object. It is filled once, andit's read up to a few times only.

Comment: If you're only reading it a few times, the cost in re-interpreting the data will likely be less than the expense of the extra memory usage.  So in that case, just storing it as the raw bytes in a private field in the structure and accessing it via read-only properties which expose the data in a more consumable format, as @jmcilhinney proposed, is probably the better option. Again, it depends on how big it is and how many you will be storing in memory.  Even if it's pretty big, if there's never going to be more than a few of them on the stack, the size wouldn't really be an issue.

Comment: Oh, I should mention, though, since you say speed is an issue, remember that arrays in .NET are always reference types, so they require allocation on the heap (and consequently garbage collection), unless there's some compiler optimization that I'm unaware of.  So, that being the case, you may want to store the raw data in a value type such as 32 separate `Byte` fields, or 4 `Long` fields, or, better yet, 1 `BigInteger` field.

Comment: @StevenDoggart, thanks. Would using `Dim newBigInt As New BigInteger(abData)`, involving a source array of bytes (which is the target of my input stream), be allocated on the heap? If not, I'd accept this as a solution, if you'd bother to make it an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if speed is your biggest concern, then I would say you're going to want to keep everything on the stack, or at least in a contiguous array, so that would require using only value types.  That being said, it's impossible to say for sure without thorough performance testing with your actual code and real data.  To avoid allocations on the heap, you'll need to create the type as a `Structure` instead of a `Class`.  You'll also want to limit your fields to only value types.  Since arrays are reference types, you'll need to store all 256 bits in some other type of field(s).  Then you can provide public read-only properties that interpret that raw data and present it in a more usable format.

The most obvious solution would be to use a `BigInteger`, since it is a value type which can store any size integer (in this case, 256-bit) in a single field.  Unfortunately, however, that's not going to help.  Even though `BigInteger` is a value type, it supports a variable length in bits, so it stores its value internally in an array.  So, even though `BigInteger` is a value type, it still stores it's value on the heap.  Secondly, even if that weren't the case, it only supports loading its value via an array of bytes or by a series of mathematical operations, one byte at a time.  In either case, that would negate any benefit in using it.  The alternative would be to create a bunch of solidly value-type fields, such as `Byte`:

```
Public Structure SideInfo
    Public Sub New(input As Stream)
        ' Improve this to handle end-of-stream if necessary
        _b1 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b2 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b3 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b4 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b5 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b6 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b7 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b8 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b9 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b10 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b11 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b12 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b13 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b14 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b15 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b16 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b17 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b18 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b19 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b20 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b21 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b22 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b23 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b24 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b25 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b26 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b27 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b28 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b29 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b30 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b31 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
        _b32 = CByte(input.ReadByte())
    End Sub

    Private _b1 As Byte
    Private _b2 As Byte
    Private _b3 As Byte
    Private _b4 As Byte
    Private _b5 As Byte
    Private _b6 As Byte
    Private _b7 As Byte
    Private _b8 As Byte
    Private _b9 As Byte
    Private _b10 As Byte
    Private _b11 As Byte
    Private _b12 As Byte
    Private _b13 As Byte
    Private _b14 As Byte
    Private _b15 As Byte
    Private _b16 As Byte
    Private _b17 As Byte
    Private _b18 As Byte
    Private _b19 As Byte
    Private _b20 As Byte
    Private _b21 As Byte
    Private _b22 As Byte
    Private _b23 As Byte
    Private _b24 As Byte
    Private _b25 As Byte
    Private _b26 As Byte
    Private _b27 As Byte
    Private _b28 As Byte
    Private _b29 As Byte
    Private _b30 As Byte
    Private _b31 As Byte
    Private _b32 As Byte

    Private Const _scfsiMaskB2 As Byte = &HF
    Private Const _scfsiMaskB3 As Byte = &HF0

    Public ReadOnly Property Scfsi As Integer
        Get
            Return (CInt(_b2 And _scfsiMaskB2) << 4) Or (CInt((_b3 And _scfsiMaskB3)) >> 4)
        End Get
    End Property

    ' More read-only properties...

End Structure
```

Comment: Letting the constructor do the bit manipulations and the read-only property just return the already constructed value would improve the write-once-read-multiple paradigma. Unfortunately using unsigned Longs rather than Bytes would introduce arrays again via the Stream.Read buffer. Otherwise thanks for the valuable informations!

Comment: You could still pre-manipulate the data in the constructor, without using arrays, just by following the same logic in my example, but doing it in the constructor instead of the properties.  The problem with that, though, is that whatever the post-manipulated fields would be, they'd certainly be bigger than the tightly packed 32 bytes.  Since 32 bytes is already double the recommended size for a structure, I'd say that going even bigger would likely be a bad idea.

Comment: TIL: there is a [recommended max. structure length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: Excactly.  This, among other reasons, is why I said that performance testing is important.  It's not a black and white issue where structure=fast and class=slow.  It all depends on how the data is being used, where, how often, how long it lives, and how often it's created and destroyed.  With such little information about the specifics of how your using it, it's impossible to say for sure, but there's enough to go on to say it's worth trying a solution like this as a possibly good way of doing it.

Comment: On the other hand, it's generally best to, within reason, save optimizations until you determine you need them, since typically they hurt readability.